# Unable to apply artifacts from Azure portal

Tags: linux, azureportal, artifact-deployer

From the Azure portal, I am trying to apply artifacts to the servers. I am receiving a timeout with the following error (network engineers are saying this is not firewall related):

```
•   NAME

linux-java
•   REPOSITORY

Public Repo
•   STATUS

Failed
•   INSTALL TIME

Mon Oct 31 2016 16:29:44 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

•   DEPLOYMENT MESSAGE
```

> The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. VM '[servername]' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.

```
•   NAME

windows-7zip
•   REPOSITORY

Public Repo
•   STATUS

Failed
•   INSTALL TIME

Mon Oct 31 2016 14:42:18 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
•   DEPLOYMENT MESSAGE:
```

> The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.

•   EXTENSION MESSAGE